# Как запретить магическому методу __set обрабатывать свойства вне класса

Tags: php, ооп

Допустим есть класс в нем есть геттер и сеттер

Хочется чтобы сеттер работал только в классе (срабатывал только на действия в классе, а не везде)

Как такое провернуть?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Но может `private function __set() {}`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: к сожалению `private function __set() {}` - сказки

Comment: Тогда пишите свой сеттер. Волшебные методы конечно круто, но лучше лишний раз не пользоваться.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.setaccessible.php

Comment: Я надеюсь под сеттером вы не подразумеваете магический метод __set ?......под свойствами вне класса вы подразумеваете свойства другого объекта?

Comment: можно внутри set'ера добавить код, который проверяет, откудова его запустили - [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/python-how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method).
Для отладочных целей самое оно. Для продакш кода - лучше так не делать.

Comment: @KoVadim и как это сделать, как определить? И почему так не стоитт делать для продакшн кода?

Comment: Я дал ссылку на SO. Там написано.

Comment: @KoVadim может я чего-то непонимаю, но это для питона, а не для php

Comment: Упс. Неусмотрел. Для меня set методы прочно связаны с питоном. Посмотрю, что можно сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Преамбула

Иногда возникает желание сделать что то такое, что не предусмотрели разработчики языка. Часто оно возникает из-за неверного дизайна, а часто из-за необходимости отследить хитрый баг.

## Дисклеймер ака отказ от гарантий

Часть кода, которая приведена ниже будет выглядеть дико, но она написана исключительно с образовательной целью.

## Уточняем задачу

Итак, формализируем задачу. И она будет звучать так "как запретить одному коду/функции вызывать другой код/функцию при определенных условиях". И нужно также определиться, что такое "запретить". Это может быть - ошибка компиляции или исключение во время выполнения. Также может быть просто игнорирование вызова или запись в лог. Но это детали реализации и на данный момент нас не интересуют.

## решение через caller

В php и многих других динамических языках есть возможность запросить стек вызовов. Просмотрев его, можно понять контекст вызова. Ниже приводиться код, который позволяет в set'ере понять, кто его вызвал.

```
<?php


# часть кода скопировано с php.net
class user {

   public function __construct() {
      # это вызов из класса
      $this->foo = bar;
   }

   # собственно сеттер, в котором все и  происходит
   public function __set($key, $value) {
      $trace = debug_backtrace();
      $caller_class = "";
      if (count($trace) > 1) {
        # в $trace[0] находиться текущая функция
        # в $trace[1] находиться вызывающая функция
         $caller = $trace[1];  
          # возьмом имя класса, там есть ещё много полей, вплоть до номера строки
          if (isset($caller["class"])) { 
            $caller_class = $caller["class"];
          }
      }
      print ("call from \n");
      if ($caller_class == "") {
        print("функция вызывается напрямую\n");
      } else if ($caller_class === get_class()) {
        print ("функция взывается внутри класса\n");
      } else {
        print("функция вызывается с класса $caller_class\n");
      }
   }

}

# а это тестовый класс, который нужен исключительно для теста вызова
# с другого класса.
class test_user {
  public function test()
  {
    $u = new user;
    $u->foo = "bar";
  }
}

print("<pre>");

$u = new user;
$u->foo = "bar";

#-----------------

$t = new test_user;
$t->test();

print("</pre>");
?>
```

## вместо заключения

Функция получения текущего стектрейса `debug_backtrace()` достаточно "тяжелая". И использовать ее в продакшн "хайлоад коде" некрасиво и чревато падением производительности. Но если произошло что-то "из вон выходящее" и нужно залогировать ситуацию - то конечно же можно.

Comment: получается как такого выхода нет, нужно перепроектировать проект как я понял

Comment: да, и есть альтернативные варианты. Например, сделать "приватный класс", который будет использоваться только Вашим классом. А внешний мир не будет знать о внутреннем классе. Следовательно, можно очень хорошо разграничить достпуп "из вне" и "внутри". Гуглите на тему pimpl.

Comment: > собственно сеттер, в котором все и  происходит - неверное утверждение.......магический метод set - не является сеттером в данном примере....

Comment: И чем он является? Магическим методом set?

Comment: из википедии - Устанавливающий метод, сеттер (англ. setter) или модифицирующий метод, мутатор (англ. mutator) — метод, используемый в объектно-ориентированном программировании для того, чтобы присвоить какое-либо значение инкапсулированному полю, например, обработав при этом недопустимые присваивания.

Comment: Думаю, что любой программист догадается, что там нужно дописать код, который собственно устанавливает значение внутри объекта. Суть примера то была в другом.

Answer (score 2):

Можно пойти другим путём. 
Магический метод [`__set`](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) вызывается только при попытке установки свойств объекта, которые не являются `public`.

Вы хотите чтобы `__set` не обрабатывал свойства при вызове вне класса? Тогда решение предлагаю такое — **удалить метод `__set()`**.

Внутри класса свойства будут сетиться как и раньше, а возможность установить свойства из-вне (не public свойства) исчезает.

Comment: да, именно так я и поступил) до вашего совета за пару часов

Answer (score -1):

> Хочется чтобы сеттер работал только в классе, а геттер везде

сеттер сделайте private (будет работать только в классе) геттер сделайте public и можно вызывать его вне класса. (также можете сделать его статичным если нужно вызывать его без создания экземпляра объекта)

Надеюсь вы не перепутали что такое сеттер и магический метод __set.

> Как запретить магическому методу __set обрабатывать свойства вне класса

Запретить - никак, но можно не обращаться к свойствам вне данного класса и магический метод не будет их обрабатывать

Comment: сеттер бывает только public! вы что документацию не читали? да и я вроде как в заголовке написал что имел ввиду - `__set`

Comment: причем тут сеттер и __set ?   > сеттер бывает только public!   - нет, сеттер это любой метод который обновляет свойства объекта и он может быть public ! Не путайте понятия (вещи нада называть своими именами )